# How to test Meteor router or Iron router with laika

Tags: meteor, laika

I'm using laika for testing and the [meteor-router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) package for routing. I want to do tests that navigate to some page, fill a form, submit it and check for a success message, but I'm stuck on the navigation part. This was my first attempt:

```
var assert = require('assert');

suite('Router', function() {
  test('navigate', function(done, server, client) {
    client.eval(function() {
      Meteor.Router.to('test');
      var title = $('h1').text();
      emit('title', title);        
    })
    .once('title', function(title) {
      assert.equal(title, 'Test');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

This doesn't work because `Meteor.Router.to` doesn't have a callback and I don't know how to execute the next line when the new page is loaded.

I tried also with something like this

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://localhost:3000/test', function () { 
  ... 
}
```

but I got the error `Error: Cannot find module 'webpage'`

**Edit**

I'm moving to [iron router](https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-iron-router), so any answer with that also will be helpful.

Comment: FYI: If you're just starting out, you may want to switch to https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-iron-router, which was made by the authors of the last two widely used meteor routers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I needed to navigate to some page before running my tests. I'm using iron router as well. I figured you can't just execute `Router.go('foo')` and that's it. You need to wait until the actual routing took place. Fortunately the router exposes a method `Router.current()` which is a reactive data source that will change as soon as your page is ready. So, in order to navigate to a specific route before running my tests, I firstly run the following code block:

```
// route to /some/path
client.evalSync(function() {
    // react on route change
    Deps.autorun(function() {
        if (Router.current().path == '/some/path') {
            emit('return');
            this.stop();
        }
    });
    Router.go('/some/path');
});
```

Since this is within an `evalSync()`everything that follows this block will be executed after the routing has finished.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Laika now includes a `waitForDOM()` function you can set up to wait for a specific DOM element to appear, which in this case would be an element in the page you're loading.

```
client.eval(function() {
    Router.go( 'test' );
    waitForDOM( 'h1', function() {
        var title = $('h1').text();
        emit( 'title', title ); 
    });
});
```

The first parameter is a jQuery selector.